# log4net config SqLite in code

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

Earlier today I asked a question about configuring log4net from code and got an answer very quickly which allowed me to configure it to output to a text file. Since then my needs have changed and I need to use SqLite as the appender. So I created the following class to allow this:

```
public static class SqLiteAppender
{
    public static IAppender GetSqliteAppender(string dbFilename)
    {
        var dbFile = new FileInfo(dbFilename);

    if (!dbFile.Exists)
    {
        CreateLogDb(dbFile);
    }

    var appender = new AdoNetAppender
                       {
                           ConnectionType = "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, System.Data.SQLite",
                           ConnectionString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;", dbFilename),
                           CommandText = "INSERT INTO Log (Date, Level, Logger, Message) VALUES (@Date, @Level, @Logger, @Message)"
                       };

    appender.AddParameter(new AdoNetAppenderParameter
                              {
                                  ParameterName = "@Date",
                                  DbType = DbType.DateTime,
                                  Layout = new log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout()

                              });

    appender.AddParameter(new AdoNetAppenderParameter
                              {
                                  ParameterName = "@Level",
                                  DbType = DbType.String,
                                  Layout = new log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout { Key = "Level" }
                              });

    appender.AddParameter(new AdoNetAppenderParameter
                              {
                                  ParameterName = "@Logger",
                                  DbType = DbType.String,
                                  Layout = new log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout { Key = "LoggerName" }
                              });

    appender.AddParameter(new AdoNetAppenderParameter
                              {
                                  ParameterName = "@Message",
                                  DbType = DbType.String,
                                  Layout = new log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout { Key = "RenderedMessage" }
                              });

    appender.BufferSize = 100;
    appender.ActivateOptions();
    return appender;
}

public static void CreateLogDb(FileInfo file)
{
    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};New=True;Compress=True;Synchronous=Off", file.FullName);
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText =
                         @"CREATE TABLE Log(
                            LogId     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                            Date      DATETIME NOT NULL,
                            Level     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                            Logger    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                            Message   TEXT DEFAULT NULL
                        );";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that although the database is created and the table added, I am getting no logging to this.

The class is used like this:

```
BasicConfigurator.Configure(SqLiteAppender.GetSqliteAppender(applicationContext.GetLogFile().FullName));
```

any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You might check this question for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382336/log4net-and-system-data-sqlite

Comment: @Dillie-O - Except that question uses xml when Richard looking for code configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the `RawPropertyLayout` instances.  In my testing, they don't pull out the `Level` and `LoggerName` properties as one would expect, which results in null constraint violations on the database.  These can be fixed by using a `PatternLayout` as follows:

```
Layout = new Layout2RawLayoutAdapter(new PatternLayout("%level"))
```

and

```
Layout = new Layout2RawLayoutAdapter(new PatternLayout("%logger"))
```

Here's a complete working example:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.IO;
using log4net;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Config;
using log4net.Layout;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class SQLiteLogging
    {
        public static void Test()
        {
            BasicConfigurator.Configure(SqLiteAppender.GetSqliteAppender("D:/test.dat"));
            LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (SqLiteAppender)).Info("Hello there");
        }

        public static class SqLiteAppender
        {
            public static IAppender GetSqliteAppender(string dbFilename)
            {
                var dbFile = new FileInfo(dbFilename);

                if (!dbFile.Exists)
                {
                    CreateLogDb(dbFile);
                }

                var appender = new AdoNetAppender
                                   {
                                       ConnectionType = "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, System.Data.SQLite",
                                       ConnectionString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;", dbFilename),
                                       CommandText = "INSERT INTO Log (Date, Level, Logger, Message) VALUES (@Date, @Level, @Logger, @Message)"
                                   };

                appender.AddParameter(new AdoNetAppenderParameter
                                          {
                                              ParameterName = "@Date",
                                              DbType = DbType.DateTime,
                                              Layout = new RawTimeStampLayout()

                                          });

                appender.AddParameter(new AdoNetAppenderParameter
                                          {
                                              ParameterName = "@Level",
                                              DbType = DbType.String,
                                              Layout = new Layout2RawLayoutAdapter(new PatternLayout("%level"))
                                          });

                appender.AddParameter(new AdoNetAppenderParameter
                                          {
                                              ParameterName = "@Logger",
                                              DbType = DbType.String,
                                              Layout = new Layout2RawLayoutAdapter(new PatternLayout("%logger"))
                                          });

                appender.AddParameter(new AdoNetAppenderParameter
                                          {
                                              ParameterName = "@Message",
                                              DbType = DbType.String,
                                              Layout = new RawPropertyLayout { Key = "RenderedMessage" }
                                          });

                appender.ActivateOptions();
                return appender;
            }

            public static void CreateLogDb(FileInfo file)
            {
                using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection())
                {
                    conn.ConnectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};New=True;Compress=True;Synchronous=Off", file.FullName);
                    conn.Open();
                    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

                    cmd.CommandText =
                                     @"CREATE TABLE Log(
                            LogId     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                            Date      DATETIME NOT NULL,
                            Level     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                            Logger    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                            Message   TEXT DEFAULT NULL
                        );";

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That would have taken me a long time to find. Upvote and accepted solution.

Comment: @Richard, it took me a lot longer to figure out than I thought it would.  I stepped through the log4net code a lot trying to get `RawPropertyLayout` to work but it seems like it's not actually designed to get certain properties out.  The above is a good work-around.  We use SQLite too so we might end up using this too--it's the first time I've used log4net with ADO.NET.  It's pretty neat.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing the buffer size from 100 to 1?

```
appender.BufferSize = 100;
```

to

```
appender.BufferSize = 1;
```

Currently your file is waiting for a 100 messages before it outputs any.