# log4net with SQLite bug - not saving logs to DB until app closes

Tags: sqlite, log4net

Aplication creates logs using log4net in a SQLite db. Used schema is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682885/log4net-config-sqlite-in-code)
Bug is that the data aren't saved to db until aplication is closed.
Durring app execution - db contain no new data.

Any ideeas?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you describe could be related to the fact that the appender buffers messages. Try setting the [buffer](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.BufferingAppenderSkeleton.BufferSize.html) to 1.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your appender:

```
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```