# log4net creates sqlite db but does not write to it

Tags: c#, sqlite, log4net

My attempt to use log4net with the definitions comes from this post: [log4net config SqLite in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682885/log4net-config-sqlite-in-code)

I have the static class used there (minus the test method):

```
namespace My_App.Logging {
    public class SqLiteLogging {
        public static class SqLiteAppender {
            public static IAppender GetSqliteAppender(string dbFilename) {
                var dbFile = new FileInfo(dbFilename);

                if (!dbFile.Exists) {
                    CreateLogDb(dbFile);
                }

                var appender = new AdoNetAppender {
                    ConnectionType = "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, System.Data.SQLite",
                    ConnectionString = $"Data Source={dbFilename};Version=3;",
                    CommandText =
                        "INSERT INTO Log (Date, Level, Logger, Message) VALUES (@Date, @Level, @Logger, @Message)"
                };

                appender.AddParameter(new AdoNetAppenderParameter {
                    ParameterName = "@Date",
                    DbType = DbType.DateTime,
                    Layout = new RawTimeStampLayout()
                });

                appender.AddParameter(new AdoNetAppenderParameter {
                    ParameterName = "@Level",
                    DbType = DbType.String,
                    Layout = new Layout2RawLayoutAdapter(new PatternLayout("%level"))
                });

                appender.AddParameter(new AdoNetAppenderParameter {
                    ParameterName = "@Logger",
                    DbType = DbType.String,
                    Layout = new Layout2RawLayoutAdapter(new PatternLayout("%logger"))
                });

                appender.AddParameter(new AdoNetAppenderParameter {
                    ParameterName = "@Message",
                    DbType = DbType.String,
                    Layout = new Layout2RawLayoutAdapter(new PatternLayout("%message"))
                });

                appender.Threshold = log4net.Core.Level.All;
                appender.BufferSize = 1;

                appender.ActivateOptions();

                return appender;
            }

            public static void CreateLogDb(FileInfo file) {
                using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection()) {
                    conn.ConnectionString = $"Data Source={file.FullName};New=True;Compress=True;Synchronous=Off";
                    conn.Open();

                    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
                        cmd.CommandText = @"
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Log(
    LogId     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Date      DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Level     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Logger    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Message   TEXT DEFAULT NULL
);
";

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I call the logging methods in an `ActionResult` method in my `Home` view:

```
namespace My_App.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        private static ILog _log;

        public ActionResult Index() {
            var dbFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory") + "/log4net.sqlite";
            BasicConfigurator.Configure(SqLiteLogging.SqLiteAppender.GetSqliteAppender(dbFile));
            _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HomeController));
            _log.Info("Hello there");
            return View();
        }

        ...
```

The sqlite db is being created in the app's `App_Data` dir but none of the log writes are being inserted.  Nothing is throwing errors as far as I can tell using the debugger.

I've seen other posts about giving the IIS 'user' write perms to the db dir but it obviously has perms to create.

Ideas?

**EDIT** I modofied the `SqLiteAppender` method to reflect current working conditions. First, based on advice below I added `appender.BufferSize = 1;` then I changed the Layout associated with the "message" field.  For some reason the `Layout2RawLayoutAdapter` version works better than what I had originally.

Comment: enabled trace output for log4net and see it complaining about a RepositoryAttribute not being defined.  will try that

Comment: setting RepositoryAttribute did nothing useful, or I don't understand that well enough.  I set the threshold level to All and that doesn't seem to do anything either

Comment: One thing to notice is the difference in your connection string when creating your db and when configuring for log4net: You create using `FileInfo.Fullname` but only use the `dbFilename` string when configuring. Might be worth a try to change `{dbFilename}` to `{dbFile.Fullname}` in your log4net connection string.

Comment: Good catch though it doesn't seem to have had an effect.  I'm just using trace at the moment.

Comment: I only ever used log4net configured with web.config or app.config so I cannot tell what undefined *RepositoryAttribute* it could be complain about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ado provider has a default buffer to write multiple messages at the same time. You can change the buffer with:

```
appender.BufferSize = 1;
```

Then all messages will be written directly.

Comment: If you lots of logging, then you get better performance with a larger buffer